# Who discovered the logarithmic integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, math-history, polylogarithm

This question is about history of logarithmic integral, which is discussed as well [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html) and is the antiderivative of the function $\frac{dx}{\log x}$. Which mathematician discovered that function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who was the first to understand that the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln(x)$, did Newton know that?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837537/who-was-the-first-to-understand-that-the-integral-of-frac1x-is-lnx)

Comment: Do you meant the same mathematician discovred both logx and li(x) ? I think no

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Retracted the flag.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? Integrals aren't really "discovered" in the sense that we know which functions are integrable already, and there is no closed form of the function $li$ in terms of elementary functions. So, many properties of this function were discovered, but the function itself was known to exist for basically as long as integration was known. Are you asking who was the first to consider it? Who discovered/proved some of it's main properties? There are many different questions with different and multiple answers.

Comment: Thanks , by the way i meant your two : who was the first to consider it? Who discovered  some of it's main properties?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know whether this is the earliest reference where the function is defined, but certainly an early reference is Johann Georg von Soldner's 1809 treatise [*Théorie et tables d'une nouvelle fonction transcendante*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_g4Q_AAAAcAAJ) (English: *Theory and tables of a new transcendental function*) [archive.org], which is dedicated to the logarithmic integral function and its properties. (NB the almost-modern notation $\color{#00bf00}{\operatorname{li.} x}$ for the function occurs at the beginning of Chapter 2.)

Obviously, the title suggests the function wasn't considered long before the treatise was written. In a 1811 letter to Bessel (in German), Gauss referred to the function as "his [Soldner's] $\operatorname{li} x = \int \frac{dx}{\log x}$" ([*Gauss Werke* [Gauss' Collected Works], Band VIII](http://www.wilbourhall.org/pdfs/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_Werke___8.pdf) [pdf warning], pp. 90-92), which arguably supports that conclusion.

In Chapter 1, Soldner writes that Euler considered the Maclaurin series for the logarithmic integral, but his citations (Tom. I, art. 219 et 228) evidently use a numbering for Euler's papers that differs from the one used by the Euler Archive, so I don't know to which papers he refers and do not know what else Euler achieved along these lines. (Possibly they are [among these](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/enestrom.php?topic=is&lang=e), and I would be gratified to know to which he referred.)